# modal not working and displaying blank screen after clicking

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

It was working beforehand but now it fails and I have no idea whats the problem, it's all started after adding the three methods on modal file. the modal is on js file and the parent component is on tsx file:

**the modal component**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Modal, Button, Row, Col, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {App} from './App'


export class AddModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email : "",
            title : "",
            content : ""
        }
    }


    handleEmailChange = e => {
        this.setState({email: e.target.value});
    };
    handleTitleChange = e  => {
        this.setState({title: e.target.value});
    };
    handleContentChange = e => {
        this.setState({content: e.target.value});
    };

    RandomHexString = L => {
        let hexstring = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
            hexstring += (Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16);
        }
        return (hexstring);
    }

    render(){
        let new_ticket = {id:"",title:"",content:"", userEmail:"",creationTime: new Date()};
        return(
            <Modal
                {...this.props}
                size="lg"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                        Ticket Details:
                    </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1" >
                            <Form.Label>Email:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput2">
                            <Form.Label>Title:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                            <Form.Label>Content:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3" value={this.state.content} onChange={this.handleContentChange}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>
                { new_ticket["id"] = this.RandomHexString(8) + '-' + this.RandomHexString(4) + '-' + this.RandomHexString(4) + '-' + this.RandomHexString(4) + '-' + this.RandomHexString(12)}
                { new_ticket["title"]= this.state.title}
                { new_ticket["content"] = this.state.content}
                { new_ticket["userEmail"] = this.state.email}
                { new_ticket["creationTime"] = new Date()}

                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="success" onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit(new_ticket)}>Create</Button>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

**the parent component that calls the modal:**

```
async HandleInsert(formData : Ticket) {
        this.setState({
            tickets: await api.postTickets(formData)
        })
    }

    addModalClose = () => {
        this.setState( {
            addModalShow : false
        });
    }

    addModalOpen = () => {
        this.setState( {
            addModalShow : true
        });
    }


 <Button id="button" className="add_ticket" onClick={this.addModalOpen}>New Ticket</Button>
                        {/*define new props for Modal component in parent component*/}
                        <AddModal
                            show={this.state.addModalShow}
                            onHide={this.addModalClose}
                            onSubmit={this.HandleInsert}
                        />
```

any idea what I should try here?

Comment: i think you need to mention show={show} onHide={handleClose} particulary. check that.

Comment: Hi Vahid Akhtar, I did that and still the same problem.

Comment: can you share sandbox or parent component.